# Convert IEnumerable<Reads> to CSV

Tags: c#, mvc, csv, asp.net

I have an `IEnumerable` of a view model that I need to convert to CSV and send back as a file response. I have written it out quite manually and I'm just seeking code review and suggestions on a more elegant solution, or alternatively if this looks acceptable, confirmation of that:

```
    public ActionResult ExportBasicReads(string nmi, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var reads = _dataService.GetBasicReads(nmi, fromDate, toDate)
                    .Where(r => r.CurrentReadQuality != ReadQuality.Estimate)
                    .OrderBy(r => r.CurrentReadDate)
                    .ThenBy(r => r.DeviceKey)
                    .ThenBy(r => r.ValidationCode);

        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

        csv.AppendLine("Read Date,Device : Suffix,Read,Quality,Tran Code,Service Order,Previous Read Date,Previous Read,Previous Quality," +
            "Previous Tran Code,Dial Diff,Quantity,UOM,Dial Factor,Direction,Validation,From Date,To Date,Kwh,Avg Daily Load,Profile Name," +
            "Profle Area,Reading Timestamp,Update Date,ChangedBy,ChangeType,ChangeComment");

        reads.ForEach(x => csv.AppendLine(
                string.Format("{0},{1} : {2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22}," +
                "{23},{24},{25},{26},{27}",
                    x.CurrentReadDate,
                    x.DeviceKey,
                    x.Suffix,
                    x.CurrentReadRawValue,
                    x.CurrentReadQualityDesc,
                    x.CurrentReadTransactionCode,
                    x.CurrentServiceOrder,
                    x.PreviousReadDate,
                    x.PreviousReadRawValue,
                    x.PreviousReadQualityDesc,
                    x.PreviousReadTransactionCode,
                    x.DialDifference,
                    x.Quantity,
                    x.UOMDesc,
                    x.Multiplier,
                    x.DirectionDesc,
                    x.ValidationDesc,
                    x.EffectiveFromDateTime,
                    x.EffectiveToDateTime,
                    x.Kwh,
                    x.AverageDailyLoad,
                    x.ProfileName,
                    x.ProfileArea,
                    x.EffectiveFromDateTime,
                    x.UpdateTimestamp,
                    x.ChangedBy,
                    x.ChangeType,
                    x.ChangeComment
                )
            ));            

        return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", "BasicReadsExport.csv");
    }
```

Comment: You can use string interpolation instead of `string.Format()`?

Comment: Looks pretty clean to me.

Comment: No need to reinvent - the popular ServiceStack.Text NuGet package has an extension method called `.ToCsv()`: http://docs.servicestack.net/csv-format

Comment: the `string.Format` is awfully hard to follow given the large number of parameters.  I would suggest something like `$"{x.CurrentReadDate},{x.DeviceKey}" ...`.  This would also help avoid errors due to matching up parameter indexes if this code was later modified.

Comment: I'd create an extention method such as ToCvsLine(...) and use string interpolation inside that instead of string.Format. Then you just need to call it this way: reads.ForEach(_ => csv.AppendLine(_.ToCsvLine()));

Comment: Please also try to follow a few good practices such as not using string literals like this and not sticking service logic in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the formatting part for better readability and maintainability, at the cost of lower performance:

```
var columns = new Dictionary<string, Func<Reads, object>>
{
    ["Read Date"] = x => x.CurrentReadDate,
    ["Device"] = x => x.DeviceKey,

    ["Suffix"] = x => x.Suffix,
    ["Read"] = x => x.CurrentReadRawValue,
    // add the rest of headers/property selectors below
};
//var format = "{0},{1} : {2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26},{27}";
var format = "{0}{1} : " + string.Join(",", columns.Select((_, i) => $"{{{i}}}").Skip(2));

var csv = new StringBuilder()
    .AppendFormat(format, columns.Keys.ToArray())
    .AppendLine();
foreach (var read in reads)
{
    var values = columns.Values.Select(selector => selector(read));
    csv
        .AppendFormat(format, values.ToArray())
        .AppendLine();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can add/move/remove the columns without having to worry about updating the header and the format, and if they are kept in sync or not.

Note:

- You can also revert to the constant format if it becomes more complex.
- The property selector can be chained if you need special format on individual property, like: `x => x.CurrentReadDate.ToString("yyyyMMddThhmm")`